# single signed byte integer bit order seems reversed

Tags: c#, mono, bit, signed

My c# Mono code (little endian OS) is returning bits in reverse order from this online converter and I don't understand why:

http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_signed_char.html

Said tool renders -45 as 11010011

My logic renders -45 as 11001011

I CAN reverse the bit order easily enough, but I don't know if I SHOULD because I don't want to bandaid the logic, I want to understand why this is happening. It seems like a LSB vs MSB thing but I don't understand why C# (or my OS) is choosing one or the other. Does little endian have anything to do with that? I thought that was only relevant for byte order, not bit order. Or am I wrong?

Why? Here is my logic:

```
byte? sbOut = null;
sbyte sbIn = -45;

StaticHelpers.ConvertObjectTo8BitInt(
    sbIn,
    out sbOut
    );

BitArray baSignedByte = new BitArray(new byte[] { (byte)sbOut });

Console.WriteLine(
    string.Format("sbyte {0} bits {1}", sbIn, StaticHelpers.ToBitString(baSignedByte))
        );

public static class  StaticHelpers
{
    public static string ToBitString(this BitArray bits)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < bits.Count; i++)
        {
            char c = bits[i] ? '1' : '0';
            sb.Append(c);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static void ConvertObjectTo8BitInt(
        object o,
        out byte? bOut
    )
    {
        bOut = new byte();

        if(o.GetType() == typeof(sbyte))
        {
            sbyte sbInput = (sbyte)o;

            try
            {
                bOut = unchecked((byte)sbInput);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Failed to cast Signed Byte to byte",
                    ex
                );
            }
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(byte))
        {
            try
            {
                bOut = (byte)o;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Failed to cast Byte",
                    ex
                );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(
                "Failed to get sbyte or byte data type."
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Picking an even negative number, or an odd positive number would have made it easier. You can get the equivalent of a C/C++ union by using a struct and the StructLayout attribute. That may make you code easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a(v=vs.110).aspx) carefully.

> The first byte in the array represents bits 0 through 7, the second byte represents bits 8 through 15, and so on. The Least Significant Bit of each byte represents the lowest index value: " bytes [0] & 1" represents bit 0, " bytes [0] & 2" represents bit 1, " bytes [0] & 4" represents bit 2, and so on.

That is, the bit order in your `BitArray` is from the **least significant bit(LSB)** to the **most significant bit(MSB)**. It has nothing to do with OS or something.